# Jakarta EE 10 - OIDC and Programatic Login?

Tags: jakarta-ee, openid-connect, jakarta-ee-security-api

Since [Jakarta EE 10](https://jakarta.ee/) it is easily possible to protect your web application with OpenID Connect, using the new `@OpenIdAuthenticationMechanismDefinition` annotation.
This works perfect and is quite easy to use. As a user you will be redirected to your Authentication Authority Server, Login, and redirected back into your app. A good tutorial can be found in [Andrew Hughes Blogpost](https://auth0.com/blog/jakarta-ee-oidc/).

Now I wonder: When I have secured my web app with OIDC, how can a backend task or microservice connect to the app without the redirection via the web browser? Is there a way to make a programmatic login? At least to receive a valid Bearer/JWT/JSESSIONID token?